# MVC Extending Identity 2.0 using TPT Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ApplicationUser_Logins_Target'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, inheritance, asp.net-identity

I'll begin with the question, as by necessity there are lots of extra details:

**How can I configure Identity 2.0 to work with a TPT extended ApplicationUser, including successful POST to ~/Account/Register**

I've been working on an **MVC 5** project in **VB.NET** with the latest **EF** and **Identity 2.0** using **DB First** approach.

I've implemented a **custom Identity 2.0 implementation using integer keys** instead of the default GUID/Strings. (I believe [**this**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/777733/ASP-NET-Identity-Change-Primary-Key) was the guide I used, bearing in mind I am translating everything to VB.NET for my project, I am C# competent but some of the quirky differences in VB.NET MVC still stump me)

I first noticed my issue yesterday when trying to register an account using ~/Account/Register, and am 99% sure that it has worked before as I have been able to create a User account on the system previously. The error I recieve is:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:    
ApplicationUser_Logins_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ApplicationUser_Logins_Target' in relationship 'ApplicationUser_Logins'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.
```

Actions with the error:

- Post Valid User to Account/Register (Type: Client, BaseType: User)
- Get ~/Account/Index

It seems to be caused by any call to (New ApplicationDbContext()).Users, which in turn calls System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel.Validate(), which in turn gives the error.

**Relevant Actions**

```
<Authorize> _
Public Function Index() As ActionResult
    Dim model As List(Of EditUserViewModel) = New List(Of EditUserViewModel)()
    Using db As ApplicationDbContext = New ApplicationDbContext()
        ' Get list of Users
        Dim users As IEnumerable(Of ApplicationUser) = db.Users.ToList()
        Dim models As IEnumerable(Of EditUserViewModel) = From userr In users Select New EditUserViewModel(userr)
        model.AddRange(models)
        'Return View(New List(Of EditUserViewModel)(db.Users.Select(Function(u) New EditUserViewModel(u)))) 'UNSUPPORTED IN LINQ TO ENTITIES
    End Using
    Return View(model)
End Function

<HttpPost>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken>
Public Async Function Register(model As RegisterViewModel) As Task(Of ActionResult)
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        If (Await UserManager.CreateAsync(model.GetUser(), model.Password)).Succeeded Then
            Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account")
        End If
    End If

    ' If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    Return View(model)
End Function
```

**My Identity Models set-up is as follows:**

```
Public Class ApplicationUser
    Inherits IdentityUser(Of Integer, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim)
    Implements IUser(Of Integer)
    Public Async Function GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager As CustomUserManager) As Task(Of ClaimsIdentity)
        Dim userIdentity = Await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(Me, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)

        ' Add custom user claims here
        Return userIdentity
    End Function

    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
End Class

Public Class ApplicationDbContext
    Inherits IdentityDbContext(Of ApplicationUser, CustomRole, Integer, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim)
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("DBNAME")
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Create() As ApplicationDbContext
        Return New ApplicationDbContext()
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(ByVal modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
        MyBase.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)
        modelBuilder.Entity(Of ApplicationUser).ToTable("Users").HasKey(Function(x) New With {x.Id})
        'modelBuilder.Entity(Of User).ToTable("Users").HasKey(Function(x) New With {x.Id})
        'modelBuilder.Entity(Of Client).ToTable("Clients").HasKey(Function(x) New With {x.Id})
        'modelBuilder.Entity(Of Provider).ToTable("Providers").HasKey(Function(x) New With {x.Id})
        modelBuilder.Entity(Of CustomUserRole).ToTable("UserRoles").HasKey(Function(x) New With {x.RoleId, x.UserId})
        modelBuilder.Entity(Of CustomUserLogin).ToTable("UserLogins").HasKey(Function(x) New With {x.UserId})
        modelBuilder.Entity(Of CustomUserClaim).ToTable("UserClaims")
        modelBuilder.Entity(Of CustomRole).ToTable("Roles")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class IdentityManager
    Public Function RoleExists(name As String) As Boolean
        Dim rm = New CustomRoleManager(New RoleStore(Of IdentityRole)(New ApplicationDbContext()))
        Return rm.RoleExists(name)
    End Function

    Public Function CreateRole(name As String) As Boolean
        Dim rm = New CustomRoleManager(New RoleStore(Of IdentityRole)(New ApplicationDbContext()))
        Dim idResult = rm.Create(New CustomRole(name))
        Return idResult.Succeeded
    End Function

    Public Function CreateUser(user As ApplicationUser, password As String) As Boolean
        Dim um = New CustomUserManager(New CustomUserStore(New ApplicationDbContext()))
        Dim idResult = um.Create(user, password)
        Return idResult.Succeeded
    End Function

    Public Function AddUserToRole(userId As String, roleName As String) As Boolean
        Dim um = New CustomUserManager(New CustomUserStore(New ApplicationDbContext()))
        Dim idResult = um.AddToRole(userId, roleName)
        Return idResult.Succeeded
    End Function

    Public Sub ClearUserRoles(userId As String)
        Dim um = New CustomUserManager(New CustomUserStore(New ApplicationDbContext()))
        Dim user = um.FindById(userId)
        Dim currentRoles = New List(Of CustomUserRole)()
        currentRoles.AddRange(user.Roles)
        For Each role As CustomUserRole In currentRoles
            um.RemoveFromRole(userId, role.RoleId)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

'New drived classes 
Public Class CustomUserRole
    Inherits IdentityUserRole(Of Integer)
End Class

Public Class CustomUserClaim
    Inherits IdentityUserClaim(Of Integer)
End Class

Public Class CustomUserLogin
    Inherits IdentityUserLogin(Of Integer)
End Class

Public Class CustomRole
    Inherits IdentityRole(Of Integer, CustomUserRole)
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(name__1 As String)
        Name = name__1
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class CustomUserStore
    Inherits UserStore(Of ApplicationUser, CustomRole, Integer, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim)
    Public Sub New(context As ApplicationDbContext)
        MyBase.New(context)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class CustomRoleStore
    Inherits RoleStore(Of CustomRole, Integer, CustomUserRole)
    Public Sub New(context As ApplicationDbContext)
        MyBase.New(context)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**My TPT setup is as follows (Db Generated Classes)**

```
Partial Public Class User
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property Email As String
    Public Property EmailConfirmed As Boolean
    Public Property PasswordHash As String
    Public Property SecurityStamp As String
    Public Property PhoneNumber As String
    Public Property PhoneNumberConfirmed As Boolean
    Public Property TwoFactorEnabled As Boolean
    Public Property LockoutEndDateUtc As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property LockoutEnabled As Boolean
    Public Property AccessFailedCount As Integer
    Public Property UserName As String
    Public Property Mobile As String
    Public Property Address1 As String
    Public Property Address2 As String
    Public Property Town As String
    Public Property County As String
    Public Property PostCode As String
    Public Property Created As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property Modified As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property Deleted As Nullable(Of Date)

    Public Overridable Property CarXMLs As ICollection(Of CarXML) = New HashSet(Of CarXML)
    Public Overridable Property Notification As Notification
    Public Overridable Property Queries As ICollection(Of Query) = New HashSet(Of Query)
    Public Overridable Property UserClaims As ICollection(Of UserClaim) = New HashSet(Of UserClaim)
    Public Overridable Property UserLogins As ICollection(Of UserLogin) = New HashSet(Of UserLogin)
    Public Overridable Property Roles As ICollection(Of Role) = New HashSet(Of Role)
    Public Overridable Property Requests As ICollection(Of Request) = New HashSet(Of Request)

End Class

Partial Public Class Client
         Inherits User

End Class

Partial Public Class Provider
         Inherits User
    Public Property CompanyName As String
    Public Property ContractAccepted As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property TermsAccepted As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property RequestEmail As String
    Public Property ClientTextGeneral As String
    Public Property ClientTextOpeningHours As String
    Public Property ClientTextLocation As String
    Public Property FeeDiscountQuote As Nullable(Of Decimal)
    Public Property FeeDiscountBuy As Nullable(Of Decimal)
    Public Property FeeDiscountFlat As Nullable(Of Decimal)
    Public Property Balance As Nullable(Of Decimal)
    Public Property QuoteReplyCost As Nullable(Of Decimal)
    Public Property MultiServiceDiscount As Nullable(Of Decimal)

    Public Overridable Property Quotes As ICollection(Of Quote) = New HashSet(Of Quote)
    Public Overridable Property ServicesInProviders As ICollection(Of ServicesInProvider) = New HashSet(Of ServicesInProvider)
    Public Overridable Property Transactions As ICollection(Of Transaction) = New HashSet(Of Transaction)

End Class
```

**Stack Trace**

```
[ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

ApplicationUser_Logins_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ApplicationUser_Logins_Target' in relationship 'ApplicationUser_Logins'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.
]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel.Validate() +259
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo) +447
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +103
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +143
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +171
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +594
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +31
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +39
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +137
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +38
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +108
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +369
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   Quotes4YouVB.AccountController.Index() in \\SEMA4NET20\d\websites\Quotes4YouVB\Quotes4YouVB Master\Controllers\AccountController.vb:31
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +101
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +434
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod() +76
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +117
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651156
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure **why** this fixes it yet, but I've just discovered the solution:

**Remove the .HasKey() from your ApplicationDbContext.OnModelCreating() table defenitions.**

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(ByVal modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
    MyBase.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of ApplicationUser).ToTable("Users") '.HasKey(Function(x) New With {x.Id})
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of CustomUserRole).ToTable("UserRoles") '.HasKey(Function(x) New With {x.RoleId, x.UserId})
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of CustomUserLogin).ToTable("UserLogins") '.HasKey(Function(x) New With {x.UserId})
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of CustomUserClaim).ToTable("UserClaims")
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of CustomRole).ToTable("Roles")
End Sub
```

Infuriatingly; I'm sure I remember adding those specifically to fix a previous issue with Identity for me. I'll update this answer as soon as I know more about the solution, though feel free to comment if you think you know.